# REST API for Hyperledger Composer to run without stop

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have managed to install and run Hyperledger composer on AWS .i was able to run composer-rest-server from Putty session .I started to work on the web application .

Although whenever i close the Putty Session , the server is down . now i need to make the server running all the time , in order to  make the web application available all the Time .

What is the right command to do this ?

Comment: well, that depends on your OS. On Linux, you could use the `nohup` command - and provide the require parameters for starting the REST server for your business network  (and then send it to the background (NO Hang-UP so that it doesn't exit when you log out of the PUTTY session). Or run/deploy as a docker container container.https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

Answer (score 1):

use the following command

```
nohup composer-rest-server -c <card-name> -n never -w true > rest-server.out> rest-server.err < /dev/null &
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use tmux if you are using ubuntu/centos then you can use following links

Ubuntu: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-tmux-on-ubuntu-12-10--2

Centos: https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/install-and-use-tmux-on-centos/

Tmux will create a session for you and make your services run inside this session.

There is another way to make your services active, you can pull docker composer-rest-server image and run your services inside that container.

Link: https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/composer-rest-server

Thanks